# Android : Evaluate Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I want to evaluate a Dialog under Android.
My problem is that the Dialog does not wait
with returning a value until I pressed a
button. And when I use a Semaphore the 
program hangs at Semaphore.acquire().
Why does it hang at Semaphore.acquire()?

Can you see where I go wrong?

Here is the main activity

```
package com.example.modaldialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDialog meinDialog = new mDialog(this);
        if (meinDialog.ShowMyModalDialog() == 1)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Pressed Button 1",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }
}
```

and here the dialog class

```
package com.example.modaldialog;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import android.app.Activity;
import java.lang.Runnable;

public class mDialog
{
    int pressedButtonID;
    Activity act;
    private final Semaphore dialogSemaphore;    

    mDialog(Activity act_in) 
    {
        act = act_in;
        dialogSemaphore = new Semaphore(0, true);
    };

    final Runnable mMyDialog = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            AlertDialog errorDialog = new 
                AlertDialog.Builder(act).create();
            errorDialog.setMessage("Press a Button!");
            errorDialog.setButton("Button2", new   
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    pressedButtonID = 2;
                    dialogSemaphore.release();
                    }
                });
            errorDialog.setButton2("Button1", new 
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    pressedButtonID = 1;
                    dialogSemaphore.release();
                    }
                });
            errorDialog.setCancelable(false);
            errorDialog.show();
        }
    };

    public int ShowMyModalDialog()  //should be called from non-UI thread
    {
        pressedButtonID = 0;
        act.runOnUiThread(mMyDialog);
        try
        {
            dialogSemaphore.acquire();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }
        return(pressedButtonID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not much aware about the Semaphore but you can achieve the same with Interface. I have updated your code please find it below,

```
package com.example.modaldialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class mDialog
{
int pressedButtonID=0;
private HandleDialogEvent dialogEvent;

 mDialog(HandleDialogEvent dialogEvent) 
{
   this.dialogEvent = dialogEvent;
}


public void ShowMyModalDialog()  //should be called from non-UI thread
{
    pressedButtonID = 0;
    AlertDialog errorDialog = new 
            AlertDialog.Builder(act).create();
        errorDialog.setMessage("Press a Button!");
        errorDialog.setButton("Button2", new   
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                pressedButtonID = 2;
                dialogEvent.getDialogId(pressedButtonID);
                }
            });
        errorDialog.setButton2("Button1", new 
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                pressedButtonID = 1;
                dialogEvent.getDialogId(pressedButtonID);
                }
            });
        errorDialog.setCancelable(false);
        errorDialog.show();

}

public interface HandleDialogEvent{
public void getDialogId(int Id);
}
```

}

Comment: I am not familiar with the concept of DialogEvents.

What do I have to pass to the constructor of
mDialog as HandleDialogEvent from the main activity?

Comment: In constructor please pass YourActivity.this, and implement getDialogId() method is your activity, so on dismiss dialog callback gets pass to getDialogId method.